# How do i create a MYSQL database locally using Database folder downloaded from github

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, github

I know the above question is incomplete. Let me explain this in brief. I downloaded the repository from this github link https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db and as per instructions on readme file i tried to create a database locally but i got syntax error when i ran a command  `mysql < employees.sql` . I tried from both windows cli and MYSQL clc. Can someone help me to create a  mysql database using above github data.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL queries in that repository are quite destructive, many starting with a `DROP DATABASE`, which can bite you if you're not paying attention.

Do yourself a favour and create the databases manually. Look at the `.sql` files and you will see the `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements. Run them one by one. This will help you become accustomed to how to create databases and tables in MySQL.

At the bottom of the `.sql` files, you'll see lines that look like this:

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
```

What you are interested in is the file name that comes after `source`. Open those files and you will see the `INSERT` statements that populate the tables you created in the previous step. This will help you become accustomed to inserting records into your tables.

Once this is done, you will have a new database with tables and data for you to work with. Do not trust just any SQL or bash script with the contents of your database. Ever.